# Algebraical "thing" having two inverses per element?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, reference-request, soft-question

I know in **groups** we often demand one unique inverse and it brings some particular properties. But what would we call something algebraic where each element has **two different** inverses?

Does this happen in any algebra? If so, what does it lead to?

---

Imagine in New York starting at some crossing we go s7a4 : seven streets up and 4 avenues up.

Then inverse (in the sense of taking us back to our original position) could be either s-7a-4 or a-4s-7 depending on if we want to go downwards streets or avenues first. It is completely reasonable to consider these different things as we encounter different stuff on the way. Different amount of traffic, different shops, different bars, and so on.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: The difficulty is that, with weak assumptions, and two-sided inverses, you can write $hg=e\implies hgg^{-1}=g^{-1}\implies h=g^{-1}$.  So, whatever structure you impose, that argument has to be invalid.

Comment: Please be more precise about what you mean by "algebra".  Is your binary operation associative or commutative?  @mathphys OP needs to answer the prior question before you can claim that is a dupe target.

Comment: Do you want two different two-sided inverses or it's okay to have a left-inverse and a right-inverse?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That can happen in a [semigroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semigroup): a set with an associative product and (in your case) an identity.

For example, consider the set of finite sequences of unit left and right steps on the line, where multiplication is concatenation. The identity is the empty sequence. Then $p$ will be an inverse of $q$ just when it has the same number of left (right) moves as $q$ has right (left).

You can do this on a grid to model your New York City example. (It's a more interesting challenge if you allow yourself to walk diagonally along Broadway.)

**Edit** in response to (correct) comments.

It is indeed  the *action* of these operations that matters. The quotient structure that captures the result of an action in this example is just the additive group of the integers acting on the integers: all that matters is the difference between the number of right and left steps.

So more formally I think the algebraic structure the OP is looking for is that of a semigroup acting on a set, not just a semigroup.

Comment: Yes, this is something like what I'm looking for! Thanks.

Comment: A semigroup with an identity is a monoid, and in monoids inverses are very much unique. In the monoid you describe, I would say that p and q are inverses if and only if both are empty. Unless you are treating these finite sequences of steps up to "cancelling" (where a step left followed by a step right are discarded, etc.), or equivalently you only remember the final position: but then your structure is just the integers.

Comment: Adding to @MeesdeVries's comments, it seems this is just free monoid or free semigroup on $\{\pm1\}$, acting on $\mathbb{R}$ by left/right unit steps. As pointed out, only the empty sequence is invertible, and it is the unit. The action is not faithful, and preimages of inverses are not inverses.

Comment: @LuizCordeiro Thanks. See my edit.

Comment: @MeesdeVries Thanks. See my edit.

Comment: Yep I see what you mean now with group action. It took a while for me to realize this distinction when I studied groups.

Answer (score 1):

Two inverses cannot happen in groups. If $b,c$ are inverses of $a$, i.e., $ab=1=ba$ and $ac=1= ca$, then

$$b = 1\cdot b = (ca)b = c(ab) = c\cdot 1 = c.$$

Comment: Yep I know can't happen in groups which is why I asked if such a thing exists and also what it would be called (since it would not be called a group). But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

For groups you do not need to demand uniqueness. That just follows from the existence.

The only thing that comes to my mind is something like the following:

Let $X$ be a non-empty set and let $Y$ be an arbitrary set. One can show that a map $f \colon X \rightarrow Y$ Is injective iff it has a left-inverse, i.e. there exists a map $g \colon Y \rightarrow X$ such that $g \circ f = \text{id}_X$. To construct such $g$ one takes preimages for all elements in $f(X)$ and sends the other elements of $Y$ to some arbitrary elements in $X$. Therefore these at least do not have to be unique. That is not a real inverse though.

One can of course also do the same for right-inverse maps.

I think the objects that you are searching are called loops or are related to them. I would just browse the wikipedia page for magmas to maybe find what you are searching for.

Comment: Yep I know groups can't. And I am also not interested in demanding uniqueness. I want a name and possibly references for something useful algebraic where elements can have more than one inverse.

Comment: I added something that you could like.